# Intellij change line spaces

Tags: intellij-idea

When I add a space for the same code line it has 9 spaces, is there a way to change this? The first image is how I have it and the second is how I want.

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java*:

Under **Tabs and Indents** you can change your desired indentations.

I think the 'Use indents relative to expression start' option might do what you are looking for, I am not sure.